# Directly unboxing a boxed int to short

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting, unboxing

I have made a conversion method for handling the database values returned by procs. It looks like this:

```
public static T GetVerifiedValue<T>(this IDataRecord record, int index)
{
    object value = record[index];

    if (value is string)
        value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string) ? null : value;

    Type nullableUnderlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));

    if (nullableUnderlyingType != null)
    {
        if (nullableUnderlyingType.IsEnum)
            return value == null || value.Equals(DBNull.Value) ? default(T) : (T)Enum.ToObject(nullableUnderlyingType, value);
    }

    /*
    //This is my try on solving the problem, but won't compile 
    //because T has no struct constraint
    if (value is ValueType)
    {
        ValueType structValue = (ValueType)value;
        return value.Equals(DBNull.Value) ? default(T) : (T)structValue;
    }
    */

    return value == null || value.Equals(DBNull.Value) ? default(T) : (T)value;
}
```

The problem is that when the database returns an Interger, the `value` variable will contain an `int`, and when `T` is a `short`, I get an `InvalidCastException`.

How can I improve this method to handle this situation? I want the method's user not to be concerned about this kind of problem, not having to double-cast. Is this possible?

Comment: Do not use `unboxing` term instead of `casting`, `unboxing` mean reference type -> value type

Comment: That's what's happening: the `value` variable, wich is an `object`, contains an `int`. Then I cast it to a `short`. Isn't it `unboxing` the `int` value on the variable?

Comment: @Raphael: ok but in this case can you extend the title because it's really confusing `unboxing int to short`, like `object (int) -> short`

Comment: Changed the question title's for clarity, as suggested by @sll.

Comment: @Icarus: `object` is a reference type, so this *is* unboxing (`object` to `int`). See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for more info. Afterwards, a *cast* from `int` to `short` is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way using `Convert.ChangeType(object, type)` (see the code comments for explanation):

```
public static T GetVerifiedValue<T>(this IDataRecord record, int index)
{
    object value = record[index];

    if (value == null || value.Equals(DBNull.Value))
        return default(T);

    //This handles nullable values, because sometimes there is a need for
    //a casting on the underlying value before the final cast
    Type nullableUnderlyingType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(T));

    if (nullableUnderlyingType != null)
    {
        if (nullableUnderlyingType.IsEnum)
            return (T)Enum.ToObject(nullableUnderlyingType, value);
        else
            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(value, nullableUnderlyingType);
    }

    //Enums must be handled before the ValueTypes, becouse
    //enums are also ValueTypes and using Convert.ChangeType with it will fail
    if (typeof(T).IsEnum)
        return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), value);


    //######################################################################
    //Here is the trick: as Convert.ChangeType returns an object,
    //it is compatible with the unconstrained T. Worked nicely.
    if (value is ValueType)
    {
        ValueType structValue = (ValueType)value;
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(structValue, typeof(T));
    }
    //######################################################################


    if (value is string)
        value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value as string) ? null : value;

    return (T)value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can only cast a boxed value type to the correct value type, then cast again to a different value type (if such a cast is supported).

There is, however, the `Convert` class. If you had a boxed `int` in `value`, you could pass it to `Convert.ToInt16(value)` and get a `short` returned. As the number of types you'd probably use the `Convert` class for (instead of casting) are few, a static generic helper method using a `switch` would work well, if you went with the use of `Convert`.

```
static bool MaybeConvert<TOutput>(object value, out TOutput result) {
    output = default(TOutput);
    switch(typeof(TOutput)) {
        case typeof(short):
            result = Convert.ToInt16(value);
            return true;

        ...

        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

*I use `Convert` a lot with database results because sometimes even if you're working with 32-bit integer fields, if some math or aggregation was done, they're returned as 64-bit integers. Using `Convert.ToInt32` is a lot easier than checking types and doing very specific casts myself.*

Answer (score 3):

Using the result as `dynamic` and then casting should work in the presence of boxing.

```
public static T GetValue<T>(this IDataRecord record, int index)
{
    dynamic result = record[index];
    return (result == null || result == DBNull.Value) ? default(T) : (T)result;
}
```

By the way, there's an Eric Lippert [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/19/representation-and-identity.aspx) that deals with this one briefly.

Comment: This is a really nice way to do this, but, sadly, we use the 3.5 framework version here, so no `dynamic`... :(

Comment: I've tested this solution and it didn't work. I got an `RuntimeBinderException` stating that `Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.DBNull'`.

Comment: Ah, I didn't try nullable things.  Why not amend the `==` check to use `object.Equals` instead?  That can hardly fail.

Comment: Worked using `result.Equals(DBNull.Value)` :)